# Merge List<PartialColumn> into <List<Column> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to merge `List<PartialColumn> PartialColumns` into `List<Column> Columns` using **LINQ**.

```
public class PartialColumn
{
    public double StartElevation { get; set; }
    public double EndElevation { get; set; }
    public int ColId { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
}
```

**PartialColumns:**

```
 ColId     StartElevation     EndElevation     Section
-------------------------------------------------------
 1         0                  300              COL1
 2         0                  600              COL1
 1         300                600              COL2
```

I want to merge the objects that have the same `ColId` into a `Column` object and add these to `List<Column> Columns`.

The value of `Section` property of each `PartialColumn` object will be added to the `List<string> ListOfSections` property of the merged `Column`.

The minimum of the `StartElevation` properties of the `PartialColumn` will be set as the `StartElevation` property of the final merged `Column`.

The maximum of the `EndElevation` properties of the `PartialColumn` will be set as the `EndElevation` property of the final merged `Column`.

```
public class Column
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double StartElevation { get; set; }
    public double EndElevation { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListOfSections { get; set; }
}
```

**Columns:**

```
 Id     StartElevation     EndElevation     ListOfPartialColumns
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1      0                  600             {COL1, COL2}
 2      0                  600             {COL1}
```

This is what I have done so far. It seems I have problems in adding the `Section` part.

```
foreach (var res in PartialColumns.GroupBy(c => new { c.ColId})
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    g.Key.ColId,
                    MinStartElevation = g.Min(c => c.StartElevation),
                    MaxEndElevation = g.Max(c => c.EndElevation),
                }))
{

    var column = new Column
    {
        StartElevation = res.MinStartElevation,
        EndElevation = res.MaxEndElevation,
        Id = res.ColId

    };

    Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Comment: “The value of `Section` property of each `PartialColumn` object will be added to the `List<PartialColumn> ListOfPartialColumns` property of the merged `Column`.” That doesn't make any sense, `Section` is a `string`, so how could you put them into a `List<PartialColumn>`?

Comment: @Travis I updated the question Travis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not too far off...

```
var newColumns = PartialColumns.GroupBy(x=>x.ColId)
.Select(x=>new Column(){
    StartElevation = x.Min(col=>col.StartElevation),
    EndElevation = x.Max(col=>col.EndElevation),
    Id = x.Key,
    ListOfSections = x.Select(col=>col.Section).ToList()
}).ToList()
```

The above does the group by in the same way. I didn't bother to use anonymous objects and instead have just done it all as a single linq statement.

The key thing is the sections which I've just used a select to filter from the grouped partialColumns to get the sections in a new list.

This has then gone into a new list that you can easily add to the other list, concatenate it or whatever else you want to do.

Note: code was written straight into here so may have typos but should be generally good.

Comment: Thanks Chriss, this worked. How can I order it by `EndElevation` after grouping by ColId?

Comment: By the end you have a perfectly normal list of `Column` objects so you can just order it in the usual way (ie `OrderBy(x=>x.EndElevation)`.

Comment: No, I meant the `EndElevation` property of the `PartialColumn`. I want the `Section` property to be added in order.

Comment: Ah, then just add the orderby just after you've selected the selection and before the ToList when you are assigning them in the column constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, I'm completely new to LINQ, any suggestions where I can get started?

Comment: Jon Skeet's Edulinq is very educational but I don't know if it would be good for a beginner. Otherwise refer to MSDN docs for things and google for tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

```
from p in partialColumns
group p by p.ColId into grp
select new Column
{
    Id = grp.Key,
    StartElevation = grp.Min(x => x.StartElevation),
    EndElevation = grp.Max(x => x.EndElevation),
    ListOfSections = grp.Select(x => x.Section).ToList()
};
```